# Tensorboard connection issue

Tags: python, bash, tensorflow, tensorboard

Inside `my_model_folder` have files:

```
model.ckpt-16320.data-00000-of-00001 
model.ckpt-16320.meta 
model.ckpt-16320.index
```

I want to use TensorBoard to visualize my training. In bash I launched python in bash and run the following code:

```
import tensorflow as tf

g = tf.Graph()

with g.as_default() as g:
    tf.train.import_meta_graph('./checkpoint/model.ckpt-16320.meta')

with tf.Session(graph=g) as sess:
    file_writer = tf.summary.FileWriter(logdir='checkpoint_log_dir/faceboxes', graph=g)
```

Then I closed python in bash and run the

```
tensorboard --logdir checkpoint_log_dir/faceboxes/
```

I got connected to the Tensorboard (I got a link printed in the bash), but there message at this link said: No dashboards are active for the current data set.

[image]

What could be the issue?

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: I am using a LINUX OS

Answer (score 1):

Can you try `tensorboard --logdir="checkpoint_log_dir/faceboxes"` ?

If this also doesn't work then replace last line with
`tf.summary.FileWriter(logdir='./graphs', graph=g)` and call `tensorboard --logdir="./graphs"`

Comment: It still doesn't seem to work. Could it be because I run the python code incorrectly?

Comment: I just run python in the command line and copy pasted line by line the following code `import tensorflow as tf

g = tf.Graph()

with g.as_default() as g:
    tf.train.import_meta_graph('./checkpoint/model.ckpt-16320.meta')

with tf.Session(graph=g) as sess:
    file_writer = tf.summary.FileWriter(logdir='checkpoint_log_dir/faceboxes', graph=g)`

Comment: Did it create a folder named `graphs` in your current directory? and does it contain files inside it?

Comment: No, there is only a graph.pbtxt file, but I don't think that this is what I am looking for

Comment: Also try replacing last lines with `with tf.Session() as sess:
    file_writer = tf.summary.FileWriter(logdir='./graphs', graph=sess.graph)`. Also delete the graph folder first., if you try this

Comment: if you tried to save the files to `./graphs` then it should have that folder there on running.

Comment: It looks better. Now I was able to open the link and see the graphs folder, however after I open the link I get the following error displayed in Tensorboard: Graph visualization failed. The graph is empty. Make sure that the graph is passed to the tf.summary.FileWriter after the graph is defined

Comment: Does `graphs` folder have data in it?. I mean the files for tensorboard to visualize.?

Comment: The `graphs` has one file inside

Comment: Maybe [this](https://www.easy-tensorflow.com/tf-tutorials/basics/introduction-to-tensorboard) tutorial can help you further. :)

Answer (score 0):

What worked at the end and solved the issue is to create a tunned from my local machine. I have run the following code in a new bash window on my local machine:

```
ssh -L 16006:127.0.0.1:6006 name_of_my_server
```

then I set up my conda environment and other environments specific to my project and changed the directory to `my_model_folder` where those files were located:

```
model.ckpt-16320.data-00000-of-00001 
model.ckpt-16320.meta 
model.ckpt-16320.index
```

Then I launched python in my bash by running

`python`

Then using the following code entered line by line I have created a `graphs` folder

```
import tensorflow as tf

g = tf.Graph()

with g.as_default() as g:
    tf.train.import_meta_graph('/gfs/project/read/dhSeg/dhSegment/demo/my_model_folder/model.ckpt-16320.meta')

with tf.Session() as sess: 
    file_writer = tf.summary.FileWriter(logdir='./graphs', graph=sess.graph)
```

Then I have run

`tensorboard --logdir="./graphs"`

Finally I entered this adress in my browser and voila, my Tensorboard was working:

```
http://127.0.0.1:16006
```